# Tooltip in Listplot - Export to PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format

I would like to export a listplot as a PDF document without loosing the tooltip information on the single points. It kind of works with hyperlinks. Nevertheless this workaround is pretty limited and does e.g. not offer graphics as tooltips.

Looking forward any ideas!

Thanks and best regards
Patrick

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}};
hlinks = Text[
StringForm["``", 
 Hyperlink[" ", "http://" <> ToString[#[[2]]]]], #] & /@ data;
chart = Show[ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], Graphics[hlinks]];
Export["C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\scatterplot.pdf", chart]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can export it to html format then use tool to transfer it.

```
Export["scatterplot.html", chart]
```

Press this point then goto the link below:
[image]

[image]

Finally you can refer [Print HTML to PDF while retaining hyperlinks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/print-html-to-pdf-while-retaining-hyperlinks) and [How do I preserve hyperlinks when converting webpages to pdf?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-preserve-hyperlinks-when-converting-webpages-to-pdf) to transfer it.